# Why does inc/dec channel not do anything?

Tags: java, class, methods

In the following code, my tests show that the methods `tvObject.incChannel(...)` and `tvObject.decChannel(...)` does not change anything in my code. Why?

```
package lab2;

public class TV {

    private int channelNumber;
    private int volumeLevel;
    private String status = "ON";

    public TV(int channel, int vol, String stat) {

        status = stat;
        setChannelNumber(channel);
        setVolumeLevel(vol);
    }
    public void setChannelNumber(int channel) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
            channelNumber = channel;
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
            System.out.println("Error TV is off");
        }   
    }
    public int getChannelNumber() {
        return channelNumber;
    }
    public void setVolumeLevel(int vol) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
            volumeLevel = ((vol >= 0 && vol <= 100)?vol:0);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
            System.out.println("Error TV is off");
        }       
        volumeLevel = ((vol >= 0 && vol <= 100)?vol:0);
    }
    public int getVolumeLevel() {
            return volumeLevel; 
    }
    public void incVol(int vol) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
            volumeLevel = ((vol >= 0 && vol <= 98)?vol += 2:volumeLevel);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
            System.out.println("Error TV is off");
        }   
    }
    public void decVol(int vol) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
            volumeLevel = ((vol >= 2 && vol <= 100)?vol -= 2:volumeLevel);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
            System.out.println("Error TV is off");
        }           
    }

    // does not do anything
    public void incChannel(int channel) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
            channelNumber = channel++;
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
            System.out.println("Error TV is off");
        }       
    }

    // does not do anything
    public void decChannel(int channel) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
            channelNumber = channel--;
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
            System.out.println("Error TV is off");
        }       
    }
    public void Toggle() {
        //String status = "ON";  //default on

        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
            status = "OFF";
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
            status = "ON";
        }       
    }
}


// code to test

package lab2;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            TV tvObject = new TV(53, 35, "ON");
            //TV tvObject2 = new TV(3, -10, "on");
            //TV tvObject3 = new TV(3, -10, "OFF");

            tvObject.Toggle();

            tvObject.setChannelNumber(53);
            tvObject.incChannel(53);

            tvObject.setVolumeLevel(35);
            tvObject.decVol(35);

            System.out.println(tvObject.getChannelNumber());
            System.out.println(tvObject.getVolumeLevel());
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I am a noob. please go easy on me

Comment: Thank you peterh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The postfix incremental operator (thus, a "`++`" *after* the variable name) first evaluates the expression, and increments only after that.

Thus, a `channelNumber = channel++` is the equivalent of the following

```
channelNumber = channel;
channel = channel + 1;
```

Becuse `channel` is only a parameter in your method, its increase won't change anything (it is not used later in your method), reducing your statement to a `channelNumber = channel;` expression.

The simplest fix of your code is this:

```
// so it already works
public void incChannel(int channel) {
    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
        channelNumber = ++channel;
    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
        System.out.println("Error TV is off");
    }
```

...because a prefix increment operator (= "`++`" *before* the variable name) first increases, and evaluates only then. On this way, the problematic statement works like

```
channel = channel + 1;
channelNumber = channel;
```

which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> It should be like this:

```
public void incChannel(int channel) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
            channelNumber = ++channel; // use either this
            // channelNumber = channel+1; // or this
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
            System.out.println("Error TV is off");
        }       
    }

public void decChannel(int channel) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("ON")) {
            channelNumber = --channel; // use either this
            // channelNumber = channel-1; // or this
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")) {
            System.out.println("Error TV is off");
        }       
    }
```

`channelNumber = channel++` means assign channel to channelNumber first then increase its value after that.

`channelNumber = ++channel` means increase channel value first then assign it to cannelNumber.

Comment: Ok, but can you explain to me why channel++ and channel-- don't work? Thanks

Comment: @Satoshi7 explaination added.